# How To Append Data In Json Fs.writeFile without updating

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, fs

Hey i want to append data to my json file but its Acutally updating the old data
please help me refine the code

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    const value = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());
  
    fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify([value], null, 2));
}

const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
```

file.json

```
{
  "server_name": "ooo1",
  "server_ver": "office",
  "server_type": "false"
}
```

what i want that

```
[
{
  "server_name": "ooo1",
  "server_ver": "office",
  "server_type": "false"
},
{
  "server_name": "ooo2",
  "server_ver": "office",
  "server_type": "false"
}
]
```

i want the data to append not update please help me with best possible ways to help me make my new open source project

Answer (score 0):

I think you need append flag

```
fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify([value], null, 2), {flag:'a+'});
```

Like this